# Google Dialogflow - Adding image that is not exposed to public URL in the CARD response, unable to see the image in hangouts

Tags: image, dialogflow-es, google-hangouts, card

My dialogflow chatbot has been integrated with Hangouts and with image/card response. However, when i added an image that is not public URL, the image is not showing up. Even though i have given the read access to specific user, it is still not appearing. Unsure if it is configuration issue. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hello (sorry for my english)
I hope you're okay
Sorry, I found your question now.

I had a similar problem. Your photos are in Drive if I understand correctly.
I never succeeded to make visible the pictures of Drive in my bot only with their urls (same public).

After searchs I created a new url with `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=`  + [id] of the picture (with public share)

With this url, the pictures are visible in the cards of bot (without in google Chat on Ios, I don't no why?

Good continuation